# Can the OR function be linearly separated?

Tags: linear-algebra, propositional-calculus

I have two questions regarding linear functions and propositional calculus:

1) How do you decide if, for example, the OR function can be linearly separated?

The answer is Yes, however I don't know how I'm supposed to figure this out?

2) Why can the function (x and y) be simulated by a real linear function? Likewise, why can't the function  ( (X and not Y) or (not X and Y) ) be simulated by a real linear functions?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it is necessary that you provide the definitions supporting the statement : " the OR function can be linearly separated" ...